# React Native - home automation from deepsyx, how to run it?

Tags: react-native, automation

I have the experience with ReactJS and I have built the web app with react.
But I have seen the home automation from deepsyx
https://github.com/deepsyx/home-automation

I have tried to run server in "server" directory but it's error

```
me:server mai$ node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'home-config'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mai/Documents/Workspace/home-automation/server/index.js:13:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

How to fix this error?

This project is very cool, Anybody has the step to run this project?

Thanks in advance !!!!

```
me:server mai$ cat package.json 
{
  "name": "home-automation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Viktor Kirilov (deepsybg@gmail.com)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "home-config": "file:../home-config",
    "home-records": "file:../home-records",
    "ws": "1.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `npm install` ? Also, there is no `server` file inside `server` folder

Comment: Yes, I have. (I use yarn install, I think it is the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it to run React Home Automation Server.
I hope this could help all newbie like me to do the home automation on Raspberry Pi.

I found 2 steps:

1. I found the problem that it cannot find "home-config" directory so I go to "home-config" directory and copy "index.example.js" to "index.js".

   In the virtualbox need to add "../" to `const homeConfig = 
   require('../home-config');` from `const homeConfig = require('home-config');` but cannot run anyway because of not raspberry pi environment.
2. I get the error from running temperature sensor "DS18B20", then I fix `const deviceFolder = files.find(file => /^10/.test(file));` to `const deviceFolder = files.find(file => /^28/.test(file));` in "server/utils/temperature.js" because my raspberry pi 3 generate "28-01131faf1feb directory.